# Moinmoin Markdown attackment not working

Tags: python, markdown, moinmoin

I'm using Moinmoin with Markdown using the code below:

```
#format text_markdown
* [link test](attachment:sample.pdf)
```

the attachment is not working

nor did the alternative link working:

```
#format text_markdown
* [link test]([[attachment:sample.pdf]])
```

any ideas for that issue? should I use other alternative code, or try using the standard Moinmoin syntax?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `#format text_markdown` at the beginning,

using parser sections `{{{#!text_markdown }}}` to exclude the moin wiki text will work

i also didn't find a way inside the markdown

Comment: I tried parser sections and it works, thank you bertl